# About lists in java

Tags: java, eclipse, list

I am studying lists in Java now. I am having trouble comparing two lists with one another. What I am trying to do is return `true` if both lists have the same name, but it keeps returning `false`.  In my class examples `DVD1` and `DVD3` should both have the same name.  A `DVD` is a `CD` and an `IBook`. So `DVD1` is a `CD1`, which name is `S23`. `DVD3` is a `CD2`, which name is `S23`. It should return true.  I think I would have to incorporate `equalname` (the method I used to compare two CDs in the CD class) somehow. What should I do?

```
import tester.Tester;

interface IBook{

    //return name 

    public boolean samename(IBook that);   
}
 class CD{
    String name;
    String color;
    CD(String name, String color){
      this.name=name;
      this.color=name;

    }  
       public String returnname(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public boolean equalname (CD that){
        return this.name == that.name;

    }
}

class mtlob implements IBook{

    public String returnname(){
        return "";
    }
    public boolean samename(IBook that){
        return false;
    }
}

class DVD implements IBook{
   CD first;
   IBook rest;

   DVD(CD first, IBook rest){
        this.first=first;
       this.rest=rest;

   }

   public boolean samename(IBook that){
       return this.first.equals(that); //this.rest.samename(that);

   }


}



class ExamplesX{

    CD CD1 = new CD ("S23", "blue");
    CD CD2 = new CD ("S23", "red");
    CD CD3 = new CD ("cs2, ", "black");
    CD CD4 = new CD ("HFF", "black");
    mtlob empty = new mtlob ();
    IBook DVD1 = new DVD (this.CD1, empty);
    IBook DVD2 = new DVD (this.CD3, this.DVD1);
    IBook DVD3 = new DVD (this.CD2, this.DVD1);

     boolean test(Tester t){
        return
        t.checkExpect(this.CD1.equalname(CD2), true)&&
        t.checkExpect(this.DVD1.samename(DVD3), true);


        } }
```

Comment: You're using `==` to compare `String`s, which si your first problem.

Comment: You should always compare strings using `equals` method. And this has been asked many times, please try to search older posts.

Comment: Simple google query of 'comparing strings in java' will yield many results :)

Comment: for content checking always use equals method, and for reference id checking use ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing strings, you need to use the .equals method.  == will only determine if the two variable point to the exact same string (the smae pointer), not two strings with the same text, for example:

```
string a="hello";
string b=a;
string c=getUserInput();//User inputs the string "hello"
System.out.println(a==b);
System.out.println(a==c);
System.out.println(a.equals(c));
```

will output

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: The result of System.out.println(a==c); will be true.String pool concept make same address for both the variable

Answer (score 3):

use a method equals instead of using ==

```
string1.equals(string2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use == for primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

use equals method like this:

```
if((CD1.name).equals(CD2.name)){
    //........true
}
```